# Can I forward declare a type defined elsewhere with typedef

Tags: c++

I know that I can forward declare a class or struct that is defined in another header file (that I do not want to include). I'm trying to do the same thing with a plain old data type which is specified by a typedef.

```
class foo; // defined in foo.h
struct bar; // defined in bar.h
typedef baz; // defined in baz.h

void Crunch(foo& a, bar& b, baz& c);
```

Obviously the above code does not compile (`error: 'baz' does not name a type`) and if the line is removed, compilation fails with `error: 'baz' has not been declared`. If I change the word `typedef` to `using` in the above example, the error is `expected nested-name-specifier before 'baz'`.

Is there some equivalent to forward declaring the type `baz`?

Comment: Have you tried the keyword ```using``` ?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  You could recreate the typedef though.

Comment: No. See for instance [<iosfwd>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd#Synopsis) from the standard library.

Comment: No.  An old trick was to put a typedef in a header, so you can include it for the "forward declaration" effect you get by including it anywhere you need it.  (And much better than a forward declaration, changes it in the header are seen in user code without manual effort.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t do this, because there is nothing at all that can be done with a type without knowing what **kind** of type it is.  In particular, `baz` might be a function type, in which case `const baz` and `baz` are the same type (affecting overload resolution), or it could be an lvalue reference type, in which case those, `baz&`, and `baz&&` are all the same type.  It could be `volatile void` or `int () &&`, in which case `baz&` doesn’t exist.  The language simply doesn’t support this level of “utterly incomplete type”.

One could imagine a declaration that said that “This is some unspecified **object** type”, but some platforms use different addressing conventions for, say, `char` and `int`, so we can’t have that either if we expect to be able to use pointers or references to such an unknown type.  (This doesn’t apply to class types, whose corresponding pointer types are specified to behave similarly.)

Comment: I know that `baz` is a plain old data type. In my particular case it is `float` but might possibly change to `int` or even `double`. Is that enough information to provide a keyword that declares `baz`? Or does your second paragraph already cover that?

Comment: @TimRandall: The second paragraph does cover that, or at least get so close that no one has bothered to make such a narrow language feature as “I declare this type to be an unspecified member of whatever set of suitably boring types.”.